# Getting delay in ble scanner callback at Samsung S8 with android nougat

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, samsung-mobile

I am working on an application that used ble scanner to scan ble device in background as well as in foreground.

It's working fine and getting callbacks without any delay in foreground(Screen On) but in background or in case of screen off, application gives huge delay ,sometime it is not giving scan result callbacks.

Device: Samsung S8
Os: Nougat

It will be highly appreciating for any kind of help.

Thanks